# I am trying to develop a keyboard spammer and auto clicker but i cannot find anywhere a way to stop the spammer with a keybind

Tags: python, keyboard

for now I'm just trying to get it to work with the keyboard spammer. So far I have done much searching but nothing seems to work.

if you have any tips on how to make the spamming stop without having to close the application it would be appreciated.

**This is the code:**

```
from typing import KeysView
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.wait("esc")

x = 4
while x != 5:
  for i in range(9):
    time.sleep(0.4)
    print(keyboard.send("ctrl+v,enter"))
time.sleep(6)
```

(thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `keyboard` module there are many ways you could do this, one of them would be to add a hotkey that stops your loop via a global variable (in this example it's when you hit the spacebar):

```
from typing import KeysView
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.wait("esc")

running = True

def on_space():
    global running
    running = False
    
keyboard.add_hotkey('space', on_space)

while running:
  for i in range(9):
    time.sleep(0.4)
    print(keyboard.send("ctrl+v,enter"))
time.sleep(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a check for if a key is pressed inside of the for loop should do the trick. You could either make pressing the key break the loop, or since your loop waits for x to equal 5, you could simply make pressing the key change x to 5.